# CodeIgniter Query Builder Class nested query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I have this query that works fine on mysql, but I can't get it to work in CodeIngniter's Query Builder Class. It's a search box with multiple inputs.

I've tried this, but couldn't make it work.

```
$this->db->like('num_articulo ', $aricle_number, 'after');
$array = array('descripcion1' => $article_description, 'descripcion2' => $article_description)
$this->db->or_like($array);
$this->db->where('status', 1);
       return $this->db->get('articulos')->result_array();
```

Here is my sql

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE num_articulo LIKE 'yyyyy%' AND (descripcion1 LIKE '%xxxx%' OR descripcion2 LIKE '%xxxx%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter Query Builder has a neat [query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) feature:

```
$this->db->group_start()
$this->db->group_end()
```

Hence, you're query would look like, in a pure QB fashion:

```
$this->db->like('num_articulo ', $aricle_number, 'after');
$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->like('descripcion1', $article_description);
    $this->db->or_like('descripcion2',  $article_description);
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->where('status', 1); // This one doesn't seem to appear in your query example?

$this->db->get('articulos')->result_array();
```

You would get the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `articulos` WHERE `num_articulo` LIKE 'yyyyy%' ESCAPE '!' AND ( `descripcion1` LIKE '%xxxx%' ESCAPE '!' OR `descripcion2` LIKE '%xxxx%' ESCAPE '!' ) AND `status` = 1
```

Note: CodeIgniter adds `ESCAPE '!'` internally to identify the escape symbol.

Comment: worked like a charm! wasn't aware of that function. ty!

Answer (score 0):

might not be the nicest thing to do, but it worked just fine.

```
$this->db->like('num_articulo', $number, 'after');
$this->db->where('status', 1);
$this->db->where('(descripcion1 LIKE "%'.$search_data.'%" OR descripcion2 LIKE "%'.$search_data.'%")');
return $this->db->get('articulos')->result_array();
```